# Getting setReloadTable is not a function for my state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a function which I am executing on a button click. It uses async and await to interact with APIs from which it sends data and then processes the response with another response which edits my table on the webpage. After the updation, I want my table to automatically update its state and not do a hard window reload. I have declared a state variable which would act as a flag in the parent component, which I then pass on to the child components for both setting and the useEffect. However, the function returns me a

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setReloadTable is not a function
> at `setReloadTable("something");`

I know it might be due to the async and await nature of my function and I've tried to even declare an external function which gets called, but then I get the same error too. I know this might have been asked before, but any idea what could be done in my situation?

My code:

```
export default function Predict({
disableEdit,
predDict,
setReloadTable,
reloadTable
}) {

const getPrediction = async () => {

    let response = await axios.post(
        "api1",
        predDict,
        {headers:{"Content-Type" : "application/json"}}
    ).catch(function (error) {
        let e = error;
        if (error.response) {
            e = error.response.data;
            if (error.response.data && error.response.data.error) {
                e = error.response.data.error;
            }
        } else if (error.message) {
            e = error.message;
        } else {
            e = "Unknown error occured";
        }
        return e;
    });

    response.data.forEach(async (data) => {
        let str = "x1=" + parseInt(data.x1) + "&x2=" + data.x2;
        console.log(str)
        
        let preddata = JSON.stringify({
            x1: data.x1,
            x2: data.x2
        });
        
        await axios.post(
            "api2",
            preddata,
            {headers:{"Content-Type" : "application/json"}}
            ).catch(function (error) {
                let e = error;
                if (error.response) {
                    e = error.response.data;                   
                    if (error.response.data && error.response.data.error) {
                        e = error.response.data.error;          
                    }
                } else if (error.message) {
                    e = error.message;
                } else {
                    e = "Unknown error occured";
                }
                return e;
            }
        );
    }); 
    setReloadTable("something");
};


return (
  <div>
    <StyledButton disabled={disableEdit} onClick={getPrediction}>
      Predict
    </StyledButton>
    </div>
);
}
```

Edit:
App.js

```
const [reloadTable, setReloadTable] = useState("");
   
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container maxWidth="false" disableGutters={true}>
        <Grid container spacing={0}>
          <comp1 />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={0}>
          <LeftButtonGroup
            setReloadTable={setReloadTable}
            reloadTable={reloadTable}
          />
          <RefreshButton />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={0}>
          <comp3
            prop1={prop1} 
          />
          <TableFooter />
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Predict call in Left Button Group:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import ButtonGroup from '@mui/material/ButtonGroup';
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import AdvanceSearch from "./advancesearch";
import Predict from "./predictbutton";



const StyledButtonGroup = styled(ButtonGroup, {})({
    height: 80,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
});


const StyledButton = styled(Button, {})({
    backgroundColor: "rgba(39,61,74,255)",
    color: "rgb(218,225,227)",
    borderColor: "rgba(21,175,241,255)",
    fontSize: 13,
    margin: 0,
    borderRadius: 0, 
    height: 30,
    width: 150,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    ':hover': {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(21,175,241,255)',
      }
});


export default function LeftButtonGroup({ 
    predDict,
    setReloadTable,
}) {
    return (
        <Grid item xs={4.5} backgroundColor="rgba(39,61,74,255)">
            <StyledButtonGroup variant="outlined">
                <Predict 
                    disableEdit={disableEdit}
                    predDict={predDict}
                    setReloadTable={setReloadTable}
                />
                <StyledButton>Analytics View</StyledButton>
                <AdvanceSearch 
                    ...
                />
            </StyledButtonGroup>
        </Grid>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Just check how are you passing `setReloadTable` from the parent component. If it's an optional param use an `if` condition and execute the function only if it is availables.

Comment: it's not an optional param, they're all passing from App.js to its parent component to this component. Is there anything else that might work?

Comment: Can you update your question with the App.js file also?

Comment: Sure thing, I have added both my App.js and the parent component group from where Predict is getting the param. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: The state is passing to `Predict` from many levels. I am just guessing `setReloadTable` is getting `undefined` or `null` in any one of the levels. Anyhow you are using async and await, you can use try...catch blocks for the APIs for better readability. I am trying to reproduce the same with some open APIs and update you. 
If you aren't using your local API, could you please share a sandbox link by creating that issue?

Comment: I am using all local APIs from my Flask and MySQL server. I know the readability issue around my API calls, but it's working fine as of now, and I'll make it more readable as soon as I get all the basic functionality working. Thanks a lot for trying to reproduce it, I can help you with the code files in the sandbox but not so sure about the API since it's local. Would that be fine?

Comment: Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-surf-sm7riv?file=/src/components/predictbutton.js. I have tried my best to recreate it, but there's a few minor errors due to the hard coding but the issue should be captured there. Let me know if this works

Comment: Sorry man. The sandbox also working fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-surf-6crorr?file=/src/components/predictbutton.js
If your `setReloadTable` is working fine, pass an arrow function instead of a direct value. I'll spend some more time on this and update you if I found anything.

Comment: Sure man, will do. Appreciate the effort, thanks.